Using ironpython from C# async-await causes the app to hang
From C# we have to call python function, in this case the nltk lib lemmatize function (which still has no good C# implementation). We call it like this:
private string Lemmatize(string word)
{
 using (Py.GIL())
 {
   using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
   {
     dynamic nltk = Py.Import("nltk");
     var lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer();
     var lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word);
     return lemma;
  }
 }
}

It works perfectly, in the test application, from a .net console app. When we apply this into the real app, which has async functions we experienced that the function usually hang at the point using (Py.GIL()). The whole app runs single threaded, because async functions everywhere, but each of them is called with await. Therefore a calling point looks like this:
private async Task<IList<string>> LemmatizeAll(IEnumerabe<string> words)
{
   var result = new List<string>();
   foreach(var word in words)
   {
      var item = Lemmatize(word);
      result.Add(item);
   }
   return result;
}

//

var lemmas = await LemmatizeAll(new [] {"running", "man"});

I understand that the Py.GIL() is mostly a semaphore, not enabling running multiple threads at the same time, but this not what happens now. It runs from only one thread, however from different threads because of the async-await. To be hung is not a nice thing from it.
How to use the python scripts from an environment like this? Any advice?

"The whole app runs single threaded, because async functions everywhere" - do you understand what you are saying there? Why not await the results within the loop?

LemmatizeAll() is not the same function as Tokenize(). How is all that related?

Your async Tokenize method does not await anywhere inside the method.  It will therefore run synchronously anyway.

@ThomasWeller single thread in this context means (for me) not paralelly. I wont await in the loop as the Lemmatize() function is not async.

All right, trying to create a not too complex example of the environment. Seems was not so successful. The main point is, that meanwhile the python wrapper function is not async, the ones which calls it is async, but all the time are awaited when they are running. Therefore no chanche that the python wrapper runs paralelly. But is called from different threads...
